# How to I read the text from popups in an android application?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, genymotion

My objective is to do some penetration attack on an android application and read in whatever error popups the application opens.

So far I have tried using Appium as a test environment but some of the functions are limited. Eg. getWindowHandles() gives a WebDriverException.

What other possible ways/methods can I use to read in text from Android application popups?

Comment: You've got to categorise the pop-up(s) into some kind like toast message, share via dialog etc to get to know what you are dealing with. Other than that, all elements could be inspected using `Appium Inspector` to get the accessibility attribute for them to be accessed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is 1 solution I managed to come up with.

Instead of using

```
int windowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
```

I used:

```
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
```

The above gives me a list of all the elements on the popup.

I would like to thank @nullpointer for pointing me in the right direction of using uiautomatorviewer to see all the elements on the page and retrieve the values needed.

uiautomator viewer can be found in android sdk in tools folder.

```
 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
```